# How to create list in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jsp

I want to create list in JS and it must be populated by 'string' object by checking checkboxes near that particular string.
Also, when the checkbox is unchecked, that particular string must be removed from list.

Kindly help me build this piece of code.

```
 <div class="row panel panel-default c-panel">
      <div class="panel-heading c-phead">LIST</div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <table class="table table-striped" id="table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th scope="col">#</th>
              <th scope="col">Name</th>
              <th scope="col">Customer</th>
              
              <th scope="col">Checked/Unchecked</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          
          
          <tbody>
            <c:forEach items="${values}" varStatus="status" var="allval">
                <tr>      
                    <td>${status.index + 1}</td>
                    <td>${getVlaue1()}</td>
                    <td>${getVlaue2()}</td>
                    <td>
                      <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="check1" value="${getVlaue1()}">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
          </tbody>
          
          
        </table>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

SCRIPT >>

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
        
        
        $('#check1').click(function(){
            
        });
        
        $('#table').DataTable();
                
});
```

Comment: you want the solution in javascript, why tagged `java` ?

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: https://immutable-js.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/List

Comment: Hi, CaptainLevii. I recommend you to read "[How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)" and you should provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). With that, some user could help you better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use simple array:

```js
const myArray = ['string1', 'string2', 'string3']


/* To add new element use .push() function: */

myArray.push('string4')


/* To remove specific element you can use: */

const index = myArray.indexOf('string3')
if (index > -1) {
  myArray.splice(index, 1)
}

console.dir(myArray)
```

Comment: @MrCoconut...your answer worked for datatable that shows first 10 values...but when we go below 10 but as DataTable show 10 entries per page, from 11th onwards, it not taking any values. !!!
Plz help

Answer (score 1):

Can you share the code snippet?

List in JavaScript are called arrays. If you're learning JavaScript, I highly recommend W3Schools for beginners to get an overall idea of the language and how it works. But regarding arrays, this link describes what they are, how to create them, and shows some examples:

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp